# How does Gradle auto updates versions for dependencies?

Tags: gradle

In my build.gradle , for one of the direct dependency A ,  "jersey-client" 2.25.1 is transitive dependency. But when I do `gradle build` it downloads 2.7 version, when I check dependency A pom, it has only 2.25.1 version, how Gradle resolves it to 2.7?

There are versions above 2.7 as well in the artifactory, how only 2.7 is downloaded?

Only dependency A is using jersey-client.

Cleared gradle cache and tried, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably another dependency in your dependency graph bringing in a later version. Try running

```
gradle dependencies
```

And it should show some insight into why it chose the newer version. Gradle has a few strategies allowing you to force a particular version of a dependency or perhaps ignoring transitive dependencies of a particular dependency should you wish to do so

Comment: org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.27 (selected by rule)
   variant "runtime" [
      org.gradle.status = release (not requested)
      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.usage  = java-api
   ]

org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.25.1 -> 2.27
\--- com.rfs.sity:oauth2.token.valida:0.0.8-RELEASE
     \--- com.rfs.ngle:auvc-client:1.2.7-SNAPSHOT:20200608.184807-3
          \--- project :porl-commons
               \--- compileClasspath

Comment: this is what i see in dependency insight , still could not understand the reason

Comment: @sureshnomula: please add your extra information to the question, so it can be formatted - thank you. Once you have done that, you may tidy up comments there.

Answer (score 0):

Spring dependency management plugin is overriding jersey 2.25.1 with 2.7, 
I have explicitly declared in my build.gradle file to use 2.25.1 by adding the below property.

> **ext['jersey.version'] = '2.25.1'**